Is it possible for an Entity Framework Core dbset/entity to provide access to non-entity columns?
In the database that I am working with, there is a table for "dynamic user-created attributes". This table has the schema seen here:
Id  BoxId   DateCreated
----------------------------------------
84  10231   2024-05-17 03:36:54.5333333
85  10232   2024-08-05 02:27:25.9800000

Id is the primary key, BoxId is a foreign key to Box table.
What the software does is, it adds additional columns to the table as a user creates a new "attribute". So after several attributes have been created by an end-user at run-time, the table schema might look like the following:
Id  BoxId   DateCreated AttrMyString    AttrMyLong  AttrMyDate  X_AttrKeywords  AttrKeywords
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
85  10232   2024-08-05 02:27:25.9800000 NULL        NULL        NULL            [] NULL

The columns are simple types like int, nvarchar.
Because these columns are impossible to know at compile-time, the base entity framework entity definition only contains the first three columns, as seen below:
public class BoxAttribute
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long BoxId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}

My question: is there a way to use a DbSet to query this table, so that I can use other Entity Framework Core functionality, but also provide access to that row's other columns? Maybe like a dictionary of key-value for the non-entity columns?
I'm currently using a raw SQL query on the table and creating my own dictionary of the non-entity columns.

How does the database store the extra values? If they are used code-side only you can add [NotMapped] properties to the entities. If you want to support UDFs (User Defined Fields) then you are better off either introducing X number of UDFs to the table where there can be a config table for Naming / DataTyping rules, or using a one-to-many relation table for BoxAttribute with Id, BoxId, Name, Value or a BoxAttributeTypeId (for the name/datatype info) You could serialize "Attributes" for instance in JSON in the row though these would not be able to be queried against.
